# Qual è la differenza tra "ingresso libero" e "ingresso gratuito"?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

Ho sempre pensato che *ingresso libero* e *ingresso gratuito* fossero sinonimi.

Recentemente, però, ho letto la pubblicità di un evento che riportava la scritta *ingresso libero e gratuito*.

Qual è la differenza?

Comment: A parte che ogni tanto la gente eccede con i vocaboli perché sì (pensa solo a “entro e non oltre [una certa data]”), qui direi che “libero” indica che non sono necessari requisiti speciali, prenotazioni etc. (e, in genere, nemmeno un pagamento), e “gratuito” specificamente che non si paga. Spesso le due cose sono collegate, ma non è detto.

Comment: @DaG Grazie, io pensavo fossero sinonimi!

Comment: Infatti, di solito “ingresso libero” viene usato per indicare semplicemente “gratuito”: cercavo una spiegazione per quella scritta.

Comment: Se non ricordo male, cartelli con la scritta «ingresso libero» si trovavano all’entrata di grandi magazzini, empori e simili, e probabilmente, più che avere un significato preciso, servivano essenzialmente a invogliare la gente a entrare; tuttavia, un libro di testo di «computisteria, ragioneria e pratica commerciale» (una materia nelle scuole d’avviamento professionale d’un tempo) del 1961, appartenuto a mia nonna, attribuiva a essi un significato preciso: «ingresso libero» significava che il cliente poteva entrare semplicemente per guardare, senza l’ansia di sentirsi chiedere: «Desidera?»

Comment: @GuM Grazie per l'info. I libri della nonna sono sempre preziosi: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349721/101651 :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Credo che spesso la locuzione "ingresso libero" sia usata come sinonimo per "ingresso gratuito", tuttavia se consideriamo bene i significati della parola "libero" dobbiamo dedurre che "ingresso libero" significa "ingresso non condizionato da alcun vincolo", cioè l'ingresso è ammesso per chiunque senza distinzioni.

Ne segue che l'ingresso libero è anche gratuito (non è condizionato dal pagamento).

Viceversa, un ingresso gratuito non è necessariamente libero.
Per esempio, pur essendo gratuito, l'ingresso potrebbe essere riservato a coloro che hanno prenotato, e quindi non sarebbe libero.

Comment: Questa mi sembra un'ottima spiegazione.